# multigraphs in postscript file

Tags: r, graph, postscript

I am creating two graphs in one window,

(1) when I display it works but when I try to save as postscript file then it only saves one graph and not the second part. I am attaching the code and the images (display that I would like to see and the eps file).

(2) How can I display pi symbol in axis labels?

(3) How can I display subscripts in legends such as $y_1$, $y_2$ (like tex)

[image: I would like to see like this in eps file]

```
rm(list=ls())
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(4,4.5,1,1))
postscript(file="Test.eps", onefile = TRUE, horizontal = FALSE)

x <- seq(-pi, pi, by=0.1)
y1<-abs(cos(x)); y2<-abs(sin(x))
m<-cbind(x,y1,y2,y1+y2,abs(y1-y2))

matplot(m[,1],(m[,c(2,3,4)]), type="l", lty=c(1,2,3,4),ylim=c(0,max(unlist(m[,2:5]))), xaxt="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Y",lwd=2,col=c("black","black","black","black"))
axis(1,c(-pi,-pi/2,0,pi,pi/2))
legend("topright", c("y1","y2","y1+y2","y1-y2"),lty=c(1,2,3,4),lwd=2,col="black")

matplot(m[,1],(m[,c(2,3,5)]), type="l", lty=c(1,2,3,4),ylim=c(0,max(unlist(m[,2:5]))),
       xaxt="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Y",lwd=2,col=c("black","black","black","black"))
axis(1,c(-pi,-pi/2,0,pi,pi/2))
legend("topright", c("y1","y2","y1+y2","y1-y2"),lty=c(1,2,3,4),lwd=2,col="black")

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
graphics.off()
```

I am not able to upload eps file, but this does not show the last plot.

Comment: I found answer to first question, i should move 2nd and 3rd line after postscript(...). Now looking for answer (2) and (3).

Comment: I found solution to other two questions. In both cases I need to use expression(....). Please check my code below.

Comment: Not really a PostScript question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comments above for explanation. Here is the working code
[image]

```
rm(list=ls())
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(4,4.5,1,1))

postscript(file="Test.eps", onefile = TRUE, horizontal = FALSE)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(4,4.5,1,1))

x <- seq(-pi, pi, by=0.1)
y1<-abs(cos(x)); y2<-abs(sin(x))
m<-cbind(x,y1,y2,y1+y2,abs(y1-y2))

matplot(m[,1],(m[,c(2,3,4)]), type="l", lty=c(1,2,3,4),ylim=c(0,max(unlist(m[,2:5]))),
        xaxt="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Y",lwd=2,col=c("black","black","black","black"))
axis(1,c(-pi,-pi/2,0,pi,pi/2),expression(-pi,-pi/2,0,pi,pi/2))
legend("topright", expression("y"[1],"y"[2],"y"[1]+"y"[2],"y"[1]-"y"[2]),lty=c(1,2,3,4),lwd=2,col="black")

matplot(m[,1],(m[,c(2,3,5)]), type="l", lty=c(1,2,3,4),ylim=c(0,max(unlist(m[,2:5]))),
        xaxt="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Y",lwd=2,col=c("black","black","black","black"))
axis(1,c(-pi,-pi/2,0,pi,pi/2),expression(-pi,-pi/2,0,pi,pi/2))
legend("topright", expression("y"[1],"y"[2],"y"[1]+"y"[2],"y"[1]-"y"[2]),lty=c(1,2,3,4),lwd=2,col="black")


par(mfrow=c(1,1))
graphics.off()
```